# Node.js internal 500 server error "cannot read id of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I originally had a 500 internal server error(cannot read id of undefined) coming from this endpoint:

```
router.get('/myvenues', validateSession,(req, res) => { 
    Venue.findAll({ where: {userId: req.user.id }})
        .then(venue => res.status(200).json(venue))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
});
```

and from my validatesession.js I console.logged the decoded Token and got undefined :

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decodedToken) => {
    console.log('INVALVID TOKEN:', decodedToken)
    if (!err && decodedToken) {
        User.findOne({ where: { id: decodedToken.id}})
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) throw 'err';
            req.user = user;
            return next();
        })
        .catch(err => next(err))
    } else {
        req.errors = err;
        next();
    }

})
}
```

Then I created an async function around the fetch which solved the undefined decodedToken error:

```
 INVALVID TOKEN: { id: 3, iat: (this is a number), exp: (this is a number)}
//In node.js terminal
```

But now the endpoint is being called multiple thousand times a minute whenever i hit that endpoint, AND theres no error.

Here is the fetch:

```
const fetchAll  = () => {
        fetch(`${APIURL}/venues/myvenues`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : props.token,
            }
        })
        .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
        .then(myData => myData.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            setVenues(data)})
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))

        console.log(props.token)
    }



    useEffect(() => fetchAll(), [])
```

Im new to stack overflow so if I goofed and anymore info is needed I would be happy to give it!

Answer (score 0):

try to console log your Request, and make sure you are correctly sending the user object with his id.

```
router.get('/myvenues', validateSession,(req, res) => {
console.log(req)
}
```